# WinAPI GUI looks weird. The default Windows style is expected

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to make a simple window GUI with a tab control. The issue is that the GUI is somehow not applying the default Windows style to the buttons. How can I fix that?

[image]

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <CommCtrl.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Comctl32.lib")

#pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS")

#define ID_TABCTRL 1
#define ID_EDIT 2
#define BTN_ADD 3
#define BTN_DEL 4
#define BTN_CLR 5
#define MAX_TAB_LEN 15

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        TCITEMW tie;
        wchar_t text[4];
        LRESULT count, id;
        INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icex;

        icex.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
        icex.dwICC = ICC_TAB_CLASSES;
        InitCommonControlsEx(&icex);

        HWND hTab, hEdit;
        
        hTab = CreateWindowExW(0, WC_TABCONTROLW, nullptr, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
            0, 0, 200, 150, hwnd, (HMENU)ID_TABCTRL, nullptr, nullptr);

        hEdit = CreateWindowExW(0, WC_EDITW, nullptr, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER,
            250, 20, 100, 25, hwnd, (HMENU)ID_EDIT, nullptr, nullptr);

        SendMessageW(hEdit, EM_SETLIMITTEXT, MAX_TAB_LEN, 0);

        CreateWindowExW(0, WC_BUTTONW, L"Add", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
            250, 50, 100, 25, hwnd, (HMENU)BTN_ADD, nullptr, nullptr);

        CreateWindowExW(0, WC_BUTTONW, L"Delete", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
            250, 80, 100, 25, hwnd, (HMENU)BTN_DEL, nullptr, nullptr);

        CreateWindowExW(0, WC_BUTTONW, L"Clear", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
            250, 110, 100, 25, hwnd, (HMENU)BTN_CLR, nullptr, nullptr);
        
        break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(
    _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int nShowCmd
)
{
    const wchar_t g_szClassName[] = L"MainForm";
    
    // Register the window class
    WNDCLASSEXW wc;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEXW);
    wc.style = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIconW(nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursorW(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = reinterpret_cast<HBRUSH>(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIconW(nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (!RegisterClassExW(&wc))
    {
        MessageBoxW(nullptr, L"Window Registration Failed!", L"Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    // Create the window
    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, g_szClassName, L"Test", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 840, 520, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

    if (!hwnd)
    {
        MessageBoxW(nullptr, L"Window Creation Failed!", L"Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nShowCmd);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    // The message loop
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessageW(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: You need to add a manifest file to enable visual styles, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cookbook-overview#using-manifests-or-directives-to-ensure-that-visual-styles-can-be-applied-to-applications).

Comment: Maybe you need to call [`InitCommonControlsEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-initcommoncontrolsex) as well.

Comment: @MarkRansom, I already have it. I only added `#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")` but it still doesnt work. Maybe I need that `.manifest` file too?

Comment: OK, I didn't see the call because it's in the WM_CREATE message handler.  That might be too late, you should put it in WinMain before any windows get created.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Do I really need to create that .manifest file? I dont' have it atm.

Comment: You aren't [requesting Visual Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cookbook-overview). Why are you expecting to get Visual Styles?

Comment: The `#pragma` you posted in the comment above is normally enough (no need for an extra manifest file or a `InitCommonControlsEx` call). There must be something else wrong. I'd recommend using the ResHacker tool to check if the manifest in your executable actually contains the correct dependency, maybe there's something wrong in your build system -- compare it with the manifest that you can find on MSDN using the links posted above. It's possible that you have unintentionally overridden something in your linker settings or something.

Comment: @dialer, there is the manifest file in ResHacker. `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<assembly xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1' manifestVersion='1.0'>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false' />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
`

Comment: Well as you can see, the important part is missing. It's your compiler, IDE, and/or build system.

Comment: @dialer, why is it missing since I have that directive there?

Comment: I don't understand I put everything and it still doesn't. https://pastebin.com/zfgGmHtc

Comment: @dialer, may it be because I need to create a resource.h file which should automatically generate recource.rc?

Comment: Actually, the button style changes when I add or remove the directive. I think the problem is that it is mssing the settings from Resource.rc. How do I generate them?

Answer (score 0):

I created a empty project which runs your code successfully with only one .cpp file.

[image: Image Description]